# Tile Grid with Coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm trying to create a grid that can be specified with a with or height (i.e 10 boxes wide by 20 tall). I have created a script that creates a grid, but I would like to make it in a way that I can create it in different widths and heights than how I've done it.
It currently creates a grid that is equal in width as height and does not display the coordinates.

```
int numOfCells = 5;
int cellSize = 80;
Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black);

for (int y = 0; y < numOfCells; y++)
{
    graphics.DrawLine(p, 0, y * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize, y * cellSize);
    for (int x = 0; x < numOfCells; x++)
    {
        graphics.DrawLine(p, x * cellSize, 0, x * cellSize, numOfCells * cellSize);
    }
}
```

The result of this looks like this:

[image]

What I'd like to achieve is a grid like this, that can have different width and height and also displays the coordinates within the boxes:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of a customizable / expandable Class that generates a Grid using the parameters passed to its Constructor.
The class also contains the method used to draw the grid in a device context (the `Graphics` object of the **`PaintEventArgs`** argument provided by the `Paint` event / **`OnPaint`** method of a Control).
As a base implementation, it allows to specify the Font and Color of the Text drawn inside its Cells.
You can add more properties, e.g., to define the grid lines Color and thickness.

▶ In the graphic example, you can see three TextBox controls (`txtRows`, `txtColumns` and `txtCellSize`) used to input the number of Rows and Columns and the Cell size.
When the Button is pressed (`btnDrawGrid`), if the content of the TextBoxes is parsed correctly, a new Grid object is generated and the Control used to present the Grid (here, a PictureBox Control named **`gridCanvas`**) is re-painted, calling its `Invalidate()` method, which raises its `Paint` event.

In the Paint event, the public `DrawGrid()` method of the current `DrawingGrid` class instance is called, passing the `Graphics` object of the *canvas* Control.

```
private DrawingGrid drawingGrid = null;

private void btnDrawGrid_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(txtRows.Text, out int gridRows)) return;
    if (!int.TryParse(txtColumns.Text, out int gridColumns)) return;
    if (!float.TryParse(txtCellSize.Text, out float cellSize)) return;

    drawingGrid = new DrawingGrid(gridRows, gridColumns, cellSize);
    gridCanvas.Invalidate();
}

private void gridCanvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (drawingGrid == null) return;
    drawingGrid.DrawGrid(e.Graphics);
}
```

[image: Drawing Grid]

**The `DrawingGrid` class**:

This class uses a nested public class, **`GridCell`**, to define each Cell of the Grid.
A `List<GridCell>` contains all the Grid Cells generated when a `DrawingGrid` is created - using the values passed to the class Constructor - calling the private `BuildGrid()` method.

The list of generated cells is exposed by the `public readonly Grid` Property of the `DrawingGrid` class.
The `Font` property defaults to `SystemInformation.MenuFont` and the `TextColor` property to `Color.DimGray`.
The values of these two properties can be changed at any time.

▶ The collection of `RectangleF` objects that define the Grid are drawn using the [Graphics.DrawRectangles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawrectangles) method.

▶ The Text of each Cell (each Rectangle) is drawn using [TextRenderer.DrawText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext).
Setting its [TextFormatFlags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textformatflags) option, the Text is centered vertically and horizontally inside the Cell (`TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter`) and the Text default Padding is removed (`TextFormatFlags.NoPadding`).

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;

public class DrawingGrid
{
    private TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | 
        TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.NoPadding;

    public DrawingGrid(int rows, int columns, float cellSize)
    {
        this.Grid = new List<GridCell>(rows * columns);
        BuildGrid(rows, columns, cellSize);
    }

    public List<GridCell> Grid { get; }
    public Font Font { get; set; } = SystemInformation.MenuFont;
    public Color TextColor { get; set; } = Color.DimGray;

    private void BuildGrid(int rows, int columns, float size)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
            for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                Grid.Add(new GridCell(new RectangleF(c * size, r * size, size, size), $"{r},{c}"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void DrawGrid(Graphics g)
    {
        g.DrawRectangles(Pens.Black, Grid.Select(gc => gc.Cell).ToArray());

        foreach (var item in Grid) {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(g, item.Text, Font, Rectangle.Round(item.Cell), TextColor, flags);
        }
    }

    public class GridCell {
        public GridCell(RectangleF cellBounds, string text) {
            this.Cell = cellBounds;
            this.Text = text;
        }

        public RectangleF Cell { get; }
        public string Text { get; }
    }
}
```