# Is it possible to add new Rectangle variable with for loop in winform c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to make new rectangle variable with one for loop ? or should i declare it one by one ?
I try to make snake and ladder map and it will be much easier if i can declare 100 rectangle with only one for loop.

[image]

I tried to make the code but it's not working.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Rectangle String.Format("Land {}", i) = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);
}
```

Comment: It's possible to do it with one, but why not use two nested loops (one for row and one for column)?

Comment: oh yeah thats what i mean, using two for loop. But i dont know how to name the variable.

Comment: You can't name the rectangle when you are creating them dynamically like this.  You can, however, add those rectangles to a `List<Rectangle>` declared at Form level.  Explain more how you are going to use the rectangles and we can make better suggestions.  If you need to associate that String/Name with the rectangle, then use a `Dictionary<String, Rectangle>` instead.

Comment: Take a look at your code.  The variable you are creating is scoped to the `for` loop.  It has no meaning outside of the loop.  You can name it anything you want, and you can reuse the name on each pass through the loop.  If you want to do something with those rectangles you will need to save them somewhere (say in a `List<Rectangle>`).  The _name_ of a variable has pretty much no effect on the functioning of a program.

Comment: If i put in in one rectangle list, is it possible to do nested loop to draw the rectangle ?

Comment: You could also make a **2D Array** of rectangles, which would match the layout of your game...

Comment: [Tile Grid with Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66523013/7444103)

Comment: My suggestion: Go a different route.  Create a class that represents a square on your board.  Properties would include the square number, an `IsOdd` boolean (should it be highlighted or not), whether it's the start of a snake or a ladder (and that snake/ladder object would understand its target).  The Rectangle property might even be read-only, calculated on demand from the square's number (which implicitly positions it on the board), the board's position and ambient properties like square size.

Comment: Definitely agree with @Flydog57 there.  Then you could have a 2D array of your custom class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want an [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/):

```
var rectangles = new Rectangle[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    rectangles[i] = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);
}
```

An array can hold many objects and you have only one name + a number to access it.

For a square, you can do something like

```
var rectangles = new Rectangle[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        rectangles[i*10 + j] = new Rectangle(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Even cooler, there's a 2D version of an array:

```
var rectangles = new Rectangle[10,10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        rectangles[i, j] = new Rectangle(i*100, j*100, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the rectangles to your Form in order to display it.

When you understood the concept of an array, you might want to have a look at  [Lists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0) and then [Dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0). They are more flexible, because they don't have a fixed size.

Comment: Is it possible to do nested loop for to draw the rectangle if i put it in an array or list ?

Comment: @Verlanderstore: yes, you can create a square playfield. I added that to my answer.