# Graphics.DrawLine () Not working when placed inside a for loop

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a grid within a panel in order to graph equations. But I am running into an issue when I try to minor vertical grid lines. This statement works fine and a grid line appears:

myGraphics.DrawLine(myPenMinorAxis, panelCenterWidth - 10, 0, panelCenterWidth - 10, panelHeight);

But when I place this same statement inside a For Loop nothing shows up.

```
for (int i = panelCenterWidth; i < 500; i = i + 10)
{
    myGraphics.DrawLine(myPenMinorAxis, panelCenterWidth - i, 0, panelCenterWidth - i, panelHeight);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Debugging. panelCenterWidth may already be larger than 500 before the loop is executed.

Comment: What kind of program are you running (e.g., WinForms?)? If it's Windows Forms, you should be doing your drawing in a `Paint` event handler

Comment: [Tile Grid with Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66523013/7444103)

Comment: Indeed. There is no time to show the steps, so only the end result will show. For aniimations use a Timer!