# how i make a sort of grid for making accurate click points?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, grid, picturebox

i need help... i want to create a window (a form) in c# that creates an hidden grid with a picturebox, let me explain: you can use the picturebox as a button, i want that if the highest point has value 2.0f (i want it in float for making it more accurate) and the lowest point has value 0.0f, if i click the center i will get 1.0f, i want to store that float in another float (let's call it "GridFloat") and if if i click the "half of the half" (the one more than 1.0f) i will get 1.5f

tried to make some logic and mathematic and tried with like / as chatgpt tought

Comment: Not sure about what you are asking. Check some Q&A for some ideas. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66523013/14171304 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/62206805/14171304 -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52044619/14171304.

Comment: Please edit your question to show code of what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for click event like this

```
        private void gridPictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point mousePosition = gridPictureBox.PointToClient(MousePosition);
        float gridFloat = gridPictureBox.Height - mousePosition.Y;
        lbl_clickValueDisplayer.Text = $"{(gridFloat / 100):F2}";
    }
```

I went ahead and made an example [here](https://github.com/RobGreen490/PictureGrid).

Comment: hi, the program is working well, now just another thing: what i need to do if i want to make that clicking the center, the value of Y it's  0, if i click the top the Y has value 1 (so the bottom is -1); if i click on the maximum left then happens the same thing

Comment: I would just change the Y value programmatically with math (Y++) so my Y value would always have a range from 0 to 2. I am having a hard time understanding your question here though, are you trying to get an X and Y value?